# angular lazyload maximum stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, frontend

I'm trying to set a **lazyload** angular module (named 'report' Module), after I configured  its routing module and click the router-link element ,the console outputs an error like this:

the Error console outputs:

[image: the Error console outputs]

**and here's the code about the app-routing.module**

```
/* Module Lazyload */
import {PublicModule} from './public/public.module';
import { PipeModule } from './pipe/pipe.module';
import { ChartModule } from './chart/chart.module';
import { UsabilityModule } from './usability/usability.module';
import { UxreportModule } from './uxreport/uxreport.module';
/* The App Module Routing */
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'charts/0', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'usability', loadChildren: 'app/usability/usability.module#UsabilityModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard2] },
  { path: 'report', loadChildren: 'app/uxreport/uxreport.module#UxreportModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard2]},
  { path: 'charts', loadChildren: 'app/chart/chart.module#ChartModule'},
  { path: 'configuration', component: ConfigurationComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: '**', component: Page404Component }
];
```

**and here's the code about report-routing.module**

```
import {Routes, RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { ReportTableComponent } from './report/report-table.component';

const routes: Routes=[
  {
    path: '',
    component: ReportTableComponent
  }
]
```

I perform the same config on report Module just like I do on Chart and Usability Module, but why did they all work except for the report module?
I don't know where my error is.

Comment: can you please add report module too?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat well , yesterday I finally found that the report.routing.module isn't imported to report.module which I think it's the reason , and now they all works! **THANK U VERY MUCH.**